# Get First & Last Name of All AD Accounts

Tags: vb.net, active-directory

I'm looking for the quickest and easiest way to retrieve *all* Active Directory account's first & last names. The intention is to have a string list which contains all names from the Active Directory, for the purpose of auto-completion in a textbox in a small Visual Basic application used for unlocking accounts.

### Usage Scenario:

On form load the application generates the list of names from the AD. I'm expecting this to take around 10-15 seconds as there's 4,500 accounts on the AD. Each name is added to a string list for use with the auto completion.

The user types the name Garry into `textbox1` and the auto complete suggests all Garry's in the AD, by using a string list. I know how to do this easily, I just dont know how to populate the list with user's names efficiently.

There's a lot of samples on accessing the AD, but none which show how to loop through it. I thought asking on here would help both myself and other users in a similar usage case.

The code I have so far for accessing a single account is shown below, however I need to loop through *all* AD accounts and retrieve their First & Last names.

### Current Code to access single account:

```
'Domain is declared with the LDAP path
'UserName is declared with textbox1.text value

            Dim ADEntry As New DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" & Domain)
            Dim ADSearch As New System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher(ADEntry)

            ADSearch.Filter = ("(samAccountName=" & UserName & ")")
            ADSearch.SearchScope = System.DirectoryServices.SearchScope.Subtree
            Dim UserFound As System.DirectoryServices.SearchResult = ADSearch.FindOne()

            If Not IsNothing(UserFound) Then
                Log.AppendLine("Account found, loading checks...")
                Dim Attrib As String = "msDS-User-Account-Control-Computed"
                Dim User As System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry
                User = UserFound.GetDirectoryEntry()
                User.RefreshCache(New String() {Attrib})


                'Display user account details

                txtLogin.Text = User.Properties("userPrincipalName").ToString
                txtName.Text = User.Properties("givenName").ToString & " " & User.Properties("sn").ToString 

             else 
            'User not found
            end if
```

Any help would be much appreciated, even in C#.

Comment: If you have the RSAT tools installed on the workstation, you can do this quite easily with PowerShell. Is this an option for you?

Comment: No I'm working in a locked down remote machine, so unable to install any third party tools :(

Comment: I'm not strong on either VB or LDAP, but I think you're on the right track here. Your LDAP filters can contain wildcards (see [MSDN on LDAP Filter Syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746475(v=vs.85).aspx)), and by using the `FindAll()` method instead of `FindOne()`, you can return a collection of objects matching your filter (see [MSDN on the DirectorySearcher class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher(v=vs.110).aspx)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the same ADEntry variable as above and do something like this. This only adds a user to the list if they have both a first and last name.

```
Dim listNames As New AutoCompleteStringCollection

Using ADSearch As New DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher(ADEntry, "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user))", {"givenName", "sn"}, DirectoryServices.SearchScope.Subtree)
    For Each user As DirectoryServices.SearchResult In ADSearch.FindAll
        Try
            listNames.Add(user.GetDirectoryEntry.Properties("givenName").Value.ToString + " " + user.GetDirectoryEntry.Properties("sn").Value.ToString)
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try

    Next
End Using

With TextBox1
    .AutoCompleteCustomSource = listNames
    .AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend
    .AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
End With
```

Comment: I cannot thank you enough for this Johnathan! Thank you so much, this was exactly what I was looking for and works perfectly.