# Error 'Expected end of statement' in line 1 of Active Directory VBS searching script

Tags: vbscript, active-directory, syntax-error

I'm trying to run the Active Directory Searching VBS code found in this question (with accepted answer): [Get First & Last Name of All AD Accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47061527/get-first-last-name-of-all-ad-accounts), but when I run it, I get the error message "expected end of statement", referencing line 1, Character 15.

[image]

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, as character 15 on line 1 is the letter "A" in the string "As New":

```
Dim listNames As New AutoCompleteStringCollection

Using ADSearch As New DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher(ADEntry, "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user))", {"givenName", "sn"}, DirectoryServices.SearchScope.Subtree)
    For Each user As DirectoryServices.SearchResult In ADSearch.FindAll
        Try
            listNames.Add(user.GetDirectoryEntry.Properties("givenName").Value.ToString + " " + user.GetDirectoryEntry.Properties("sn").Value.ToString)
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try

    Next
End Using

With TextBox1
    .AutoCompleteCustomSource = listNames
    .AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend
    .AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
End With
```

I tried putting a line in front of the code above:

`Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")`

but that simply changes the error message to read "expected end of statement", on line 2, Character 15, rather than line 1, meaning its still happening in the same place.

I'm running this code on a Windows 7 Professional Workstation and using Active Directory 2012 R2.

Comment: VBScript is not VB, VBA or VB.Net. It doesn't support the `As` keyword as VBScript is typeless *(all data-types are a subtype of `Variant`)*. It takes five minutes to look this information up - [VBScript Data Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9e7a57cf(v=vs.84).aspx)

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) The answer, *"A lot. An absurd amount. More than you think you are capable of. After you have reached the end of your rope and the pain of not having the answer exceeds the vast amount of shame received by posting your question, that's when you can go ahead and ask. Because at that point, you will have done whatever research necessary to make it a good question worth asking!"*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code snippet you have posted is not VBScript, if you try to run this using the Windows Scripting Host it will fail.

The error you receive

> Expected end of statement

is as you suspect related to the `As` keyword. The reason for this is VBScript is typeless and doesn't support strongly typed variables so has no idea what `As` is or what to do with it. The code looks more like [vb.net](/questions/tagged/vb.net) than [vbscript](/questions/tagged/vbscript) which might be the problem.

See [VBScript Data Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9e7a57cf(v=vs.84).aspx) *(This is a useful resource)*

> *VBScript has only one data type called a Variant. A Variant is a special kind of data type that can contain different kinds of information, depending on how it is used. Because Variant is the only data type in VBScript, it is also the data type returned by all functions in VBScript.*